# HABTM Checkboxes using simpleform gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have three models, and i am trying to save onto a third table using simple form gem and checkboxes.

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :skills, through: :skillships
end
```

The second model is

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :works, through: :skillships
end
```

The third is

```
class Skillship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :work
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Using the Work model i am trying to save the data on the skillship table. Something similar to this http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised.  Can you please help.

**EDIT**

The form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@work) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :title, :label => 'Project Title' %>
    <%= f.input :excerpt, :as => :text %>

   <fieldset>
   <legend>Skills Used </legend> 
      Would like to check the skills i used here.
   </fieldset>


  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried..

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "work[skill_ids][]", nil %>
<% Skill.all.each do |skill| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "work[skill_ids][]", skill.id, @work.skill_ids.include?(skill.id), id: dom_id(skill) %>
  <%= label_tag dom_id(skill), skill.title %><br>
<% end %>
```

The reason i'm doing this it because work can have many skills used.

Comment: Hi Vezu, if you can explain your need clearly would help you get the answer quickly. Can you also put the code for the form you are using to save the data?

Comment: hi @abhi I added added the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going about this the wrong way. A join table solved the problem.

```
rails g migration create_skills_works_table
```

Then

```
class CreateSkillsWorksTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :skills_works, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :skill
        t.references :work
   end

    add_index :skills_works, [:skill_id, :work_id]
    add_index :skills_works, [:work_id, :skill_id]

  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :skills_works
  end

end
```

Using simple form on the work view.

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Skills Used </legend> 
        <%= f.association :skills %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What are the model associations?

Comment: @markhorrocks you might want to read more from here. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html